# Is it possible to suppress the false positive typo warning for hex values in AndroidStudio/IntelliJ?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, hex, spell-checking

Sometimes hex values have enough alpha characters in them that the Inspections algorithm in Android Studio/Intellij mis-identifies them as typos.  For example, it mis-identifies "dfab" in the following as a typo:

```
private static final String FOO = "6036aae7-9b4d-4ecd-a81f-dfab4b871039";
```

I generally find the typo checking helpful so I don't want to disable it completely.  I also don't want to suppress typo checking for the file.  Further, I do not want to add "dfab" to the dictionary because it is not a valid word and I want the spell checker to flag it in other contexts.

Is there any way to suppress the typo warning in Android Studio/IntelliJ in this situation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can suppress the warning using annotation `@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")` for the field.